# How do I make C# DateTime show the non-American date

Tags: c#, date, datetime

How do I make C# `DateTime` show the date format correctly?

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("d/M/yyyy")
```

That should've outputted

```
5/5/2020
```

Instead C# `DateTime` got this bug that outputs the American date instead

```
5/5/2020
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the difference between your expected output and the actual output?

Comment: Edit the question and use an example where the output is different when the different formatting is applied. This example the output is expected to be the same because the day and month are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToString Method to output a specific "culture": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1

Example:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this fix your problem:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Or this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cultureinfo class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1):

---

```
    DateTime today= DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(today.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

---

For a custome culture use:

---

```
    DateTime today= DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(today.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ch-CH"))); //us-US, de-DE etc...
```